# Low resources usage when using dedupe python

Tags: python, pyspark, record-linkage, python-dedupe

I need to find duplicates in a large dataset, so I'm testing [dedupe](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe) python library.

I know it is recommended for small datasets, so I thought using a good machine could improve the performance. I have a machine with 56 GB RAM and I'm running a test similar to ["csv_example"](http://dedupeio.github.io/dedupe-examples/docs/csv_example.html) for a dataset with 200000 rows. It works but the memory usage is very low and so the processing(CPU).

It seems to take too long in the blocking stage:

```
INFO:dedupe.blocking:10000, 110.6458142 seconds
INFO:dedupe.blocking:20000, 300.6112282 seconds
INFO:dedupe.blocking:30000, 557.1010122 seconds
INFO:dedupe.blocking:40000, 915.3087222 seconds
```

Could anyone help me to improve the usage or tell me if there is any library/setting that makes the program use more available resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of dedupe are your running? As of `1.6.8`, it should handle a record set of this size pretty easily.

However, the general guidance is that when your run into memory problems, switch to do blocking with a database like in the [postgres](https://github.com/dedupeio/dedupe-examples/tree/master/pgsql_big_dedupe_example) example.

(I'm a main author of dedupe).

Comment: Thanks! dedupe is a great library. is posible use this library in spark to dedupe 3000000 records? :)

Comment: I don't know anything about spark, but dedupe should be able to handle 3 millions records pretty easily.

Comment: It takes over 20mins to run the Postgres example you mentioned above. Am I doing something wrong? or is this to be expected? It would be really great to speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

I have succesfully used dedupe python library to deduplicate 16 million records, however 16M records will not fit into computer memory so I deduped by  X number of records at a time (via postgres) ie. at 10,000 records the worst case scenario is maxing out the RAM at 64GB of our EC2 instance.

https://ronbeltran.pages.dev/2022/08/using-python-dedupe-library-millions-records/

Comment: doesn't the dedupe quality go down by processing the items in chunks?